# Can an Android marketplace account have more than one login?

Tags: android, google-play

I am an iOS and Android developer, but newer to the Android Marketplace.

On iOS, you can have multiple iTunes Connect & developer.apple.com accounts to access provisioning, applications, stats, etc.

Is such a thing possible on Android?  When I log into the marketplace to upload an app, I see no links referring to "settings" or really anything other than "Upload an app".

2 reasons:  1, I paid the $25 fee with my private Gmail account - want to change that to company email.  2, I have a client that wants to have multiple logins to the marketplace backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot link to other accounts. However, recently Google started to let developers to transfer application ownership to other accounts.

"If you would like to change the Google Account that you use to publish your applications, we are able to transfer applications to a new account. When applications are transferred, all ratings, comments, metrics, and users will be preserved."

The process is described here:

(http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't link other logins to the publisher account.

You can, however, change the account (google will migrate your apps to the new account and refund the fee). Instructions [here](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - same information as below, but Edison's answer copies the relevant bit -- I understand that SO is now encouraging us to not only link to things but include the relevant snippets (in case the links go dead, etc).  Anyway thanks!  ... but I'm accepting the other answer :(  Have to pick one..

Answer (score 1):

Now I see a new link on my developer console to manage user accounts and there is a message which says:

> Account owner and user access
>
> Starting on March 29, we are adding
> support for account owner and user roles within developer accounts. Go
> to our Help Center to learn more about what account owners and users
> can do.
>
> [Learn
> more](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/support/bin/answer.py?answer=2528691)